# Can't access my web application on amazon ec2

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, url, model-view-controller, amazon-ec2

I've deployed my web application to Amazon AWS but I can't access it via browsers.
I deployed through WebDeploy in VS. So that worked.
I exported a SQL database to a RDS instance through my SQL manager. That worked also.

I've read many answers and I don't know what I'm missing.

I've even created an one simple liner "hello world" bogus index.html in order to check if the problem was in the application itself.

the firewall port 80 is open {I even read somewhere it was 8787}, security group is applied and it has port 80 open also.

the files are on c:\inetbub\wwwroot

Thanks for any insight

Comment: I meant c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: What happens if you login to the EC2 instance and type http:// localhost in a web browser?

Comment: Thanks.

You pointed me in the right direction.
In IIS manager I had to correct one binding and apparently one further ASP.NET installation was also needed